# Jquery select tag \ checkboxes with fusion tables

Tags: jquery, android, google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile, google-fusion-tables

before starting, just let my say that my background is primarily in graphic design, therefore my knowledge of coding is ... limited! So be gentle :D

Here my situation: I'm building a phonegap app for android with google maps api \ fusion tables \ jquery mobile.
I've a list of checkboxes that trigger various type of markers from fusion tables, I've passed the state of checkboxes via jquery.
Here's the function that filters the elements from the fusion tables:

```
function toggleMarkers(layer2) { 
    var fusione = TABLE ID ;
    var arr_numero = [];
    var idx = 0;
    if (document.getElementById('toggleID').checked)   { 
        arr_numero[idx] = 1;
        idx++;
    }                                    
    lista_numero = arr_numero.join(',');
    if (lista_numero == "") {
        lista_numero = "'no_selection'";
    }
    layer2.setQuery("SELECT Location FROM "+ fusione +" WHERE numero IN (" + lista_numero + ")");
}
```

... here's the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="MYID" onclick="toggleMarkers(layer2);" />
```

.. and the JQ that "enables" the checkbox:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
  $("#toggleID").change(function() {toggleMarkers(layer2);});
});
```

SO, ;) this solution works pretty well but I would like to switch to select and option tags so it uses the native list UI of the OS!

Something like this:

```
<select  size="1" id="listazza" multiple="multiple">

  <option onclick="toggleMarkers(layer2);" onselect="toggleMarkers(layer2);" value="2" id="toggleID">ID</option>  

</select>
```

What kind of code do I have to use in JQ to trigger the option tag value?

Hope this is clear enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with ( switch to and tags so it uses the native list UI of the OS!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, the code for handling changes to a select list should be exactly the same as your checkbox example, but with the `Id` changed:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    $("#listazza").change(function() { toggleMarkers(layer2); });
});
```

You can also remove the ugly `onclick` and `onselect` attributes from your HTML, as if you amend the above line of jQuery, this will take care of those for you too:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    $("#listazza").live("change click", function() { toggleMarkers(layer2); });
})
```

HTML

```
<select id="listazza" multiple="multiple" size="1">
    <option value="2">ID</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this does not work, seems that the id is undefined, It's unable to get the checked status from the if in js

Comment: Ok, now it's work:

    `<select id="listazza" name="Markers" multiple="multiple">
        <option  id="toggleID">NAME</option>
    </select>`

with your JQ:

`$("#listazza").live("change click", function() { toggleMarkers(layer2); });

and most important, I've changed the js in:

    if (document.getElementById('toggleID').selected)   { 
            arr_numero[idx] = 1;
            idx++;
        }`  

Really thanks for help!!